# Benefits of using lag operator notation as opposed to subscripts

Tags: time-series, notation, lags

I have a number of random variables that start at some initial state and then vary along time, I am planning on doing relatively straightforward analysis (nothing that the use of lag operators would greatly simplify).

I am debating on whether to use the lag operator or simple subscripts in my writeup. Lag operators seem to have a clear benefit if there is no significant initial state to call $n=0$. It also seems that some algorithms can be much clearer if lag operator notation is used. Otherwise, it seems to add unnecessary complexity.

To be explicit, the lag operator $L$ can be used in the following way where $x$ is a variable at time step $n$:
$$
Lx_n = x_{n-1}
$$

**Is there any rule for when to use lag operators vs subscripts in notation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of the lag operator is that it allows you to use polynomial analysis of models, and put models into alternative forms via polynomial inversion, etc.  If you are not doing any of that then it is unlikely that the lag operator will be of benefit, and you may be better off just using subscript notation.  I really doesn't matter whether your sequence has a starting value at $n=0$ or if it is a sequence that is unbounded in both directions --- in either case you can use subscript notation for your defining model equations.